# LOWER + COALESCING

Tags: mysql, sql

Why is it that I am able to `LOWER` each of the items within a `COALESCE`, but I'm not able to `LOWER` the entire `COALESCE`, or else I run into a syntax error? For example:

```
SELECT COALESCE(LOWER(google_provider_name), LOWER(name)), name FROM main_provider
```

Comment: Both are working fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64885/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem with both variants so far http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/7239

```
SELECT COALESCE(LOWER('google_provider_name'), LOWER('name'));

SELECT LOWER(COALESCE('google_provider_name', 'name') );
```